# Is better mutate Pinia state inside actions or inside component?

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I have this function in my Pinia store:

```
async function getCurrentUser(){
    let user: User | undefined = undefined;
    if (auth.currentUser?.uid) {
      user = await getUserById(auth.currentUser.uid)
      state.value.currentUser = user;
    }
  }
```

So, inside a component I just need to call:
`userStore.getCurrentUser();`
And I will get access to the current user from the state:
`userStore.state.currentUser`
But this approach confuses me, because we are mutating the state inside the get function.

Therefore, I think it would be better to do this (inside a component):

```
userStore.state.currentUser = await getUserById(auth.currentUser.uid)
userStore.state.currentUser //Do whatever you want
```

Which option is better? I can't make up my mind.

This question is more about the approach rather than the specific implementation (in the form of the getCurrentUser function)

Comment: This is what actions are for. Global store isn't just a glorified global state, it's a good practice for it to contain related business logic instead of scattering it across the app. Mutating a store outside wasn't considered a good practice in Vuex for several reasons, some are still there in Pinia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be more appropriate to rename the function to `setCurrentUser()` rather than `getCurrentUser()` to make its purpose clearer and avoid confusion. By using the naming convention of set followed by the name of the state property, it indicates that the function is responsible for updating the `currentUser` state in the Pinia store.

In Pinia, it is common to provide separate functions for reading and updating the state. The store exposes the state object for components to read, allowing them to access the current user using `userStore.state.currentUser`. To update the state, components can call the `setCurrentUser()` function in the store

Comment: Yes, you seem to be right. But wouldn't it be better to name the function `fetchCurrentUser()`? Because `setCurrentUser()` implies at least one argument

Comment: Yes, I think the function names `fetchCurrentUser`, `setCurrentUser`, or even `updateCurrentUser` are all concise and effective options.